# Connecting two motors in series

Tags: motor, transformer, ac, dc, back-emf

I have a 240-volt mains supply and I want to run two identical BLDC motors rated at 120 volts each. Without the need for a transformer with just the help of IGBTs and inverter can I run the motors? Connecting in series might work, but what about back emf? Basically is it possible to divide the voltage by a factor of two when using identical BLDC motors? If not, will it work for an ac motor?

Comment: How would you even *connect* BLDC motors in series?  To start you would have to have a winding without common legs, ie, 6 wires coming out instead of 3.  Depending on the voltage ratings involved, it is possible that you could just use the bus voltage directly with low duty cycle, but that sounds more like the voltage range where you find the related but distinct technology of induction motors rather than BLDC's.  Or are these not "motors" but rather "motor-driver *systems*" ?

Answer (score 3):

You can not connect BLDC motors in series. It is possible to connect the armatures of two commutator type DC motors in series with the shafts mechanically coupled together essentially driving the same load. Torque sharing is accomplished by separately adjusting the field currents.

There is not likely any other type of motor that will work with any type of series connection.